# HTTP 303 redirect after database insert

Tags: php, server

I'm using 303 HTTP response code when a user inserts data in the database so I can redirect him to another URI.

But I've been surprised that the server’s response to the browser is to send a request to the new URI.

I use a lot of 303 on my website.

So does anyone know how, for a performance boost, let the server send the HTML of the new URI directly to the browser (along with some header telling the browser to change the URL bar address) so that the back and forth is reduced?

I mean like a shortcut to generate the same output.

Comment: See `header('Location: xxx.php');` [In the PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: yeah i’m doing just that.

Comment: but the means that one extra request/response must be performed

Comment: Maybe you mean you want to look at AJAX

Comment: what i want, for speed reasons, is the server directly sending the actual html. Instead of sending just a header telling the browser to fetch on another uri, which will make the browser send another request to the server and the server responding.

Comment: yeah ajax could be good

Comment: but isn’t there a full server alternative? because with ajax, the same time waste is available because i’ll be waiting for the 200 status code so that i make sure the data was inserted before making a request and get the new page (which contains the inserted data, that’s why i’m waiting)

Comment: so what i need is send a normal 200 code from the server with the new html but need to update the url bar address so that if the user reloads the page, the post request submission isn’t sent again and again.

Answer (score 0):

A redirect will cause an extra request, as that's kind of the purpose of the redirect.

The one way I can think of that can optimize this, is by using a HTTP/2 Push of the target resource. Browsers should pick this up. I don't know how to accomplish this with PHP, but with Node.js or Go this is relatively easy to accomplish.